# how can docker containers have a different flavor than the host

Tags: docker, coreos

My understanding of linux containers is that each container uses the same host kernel, and any installations on the container are just an isolated filesystem layer over the host.

I was going through coreos getting started guide. In that it shows how an ubuntu container can be started on a host containing coreos.

How is this possible ? How can the host and the container have different flavours ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Answer (score 8):

The kernel and the userland are two different things. The kernel will be almost the same across all distributions. Of course, each distributions will have slightly different settings. For instance, one distribution might decide to exclude some drivers because they aren't completely free. Another might decide to include extra features (like Debian and Ubuntu have AUFS support, which is usually not found in other distro's kernels). Red Hat has their own "battle tested" kernel, which is essentially 2.6.32 with tons of stability fixes (it sounds old, but it's insanely reliable).

99% of the time, you can boot distro X with the kernel of distro Y without a problem. And that's why it's OK to run a Ubuntu container on a CoreOS host: the container is exclusively userland. It's just a bunch of processes running on the machine, and as long as the kernel supports namespaces and control groups (the low level features needed to run Linux Containers), it doesn't matter where the kernel comes from.

Comment: thanks for clarifying that. However consider the case of booting a debian based distro container on a fedora based host. Now both of these have different package managers. So will that conflict? If not why ? Also what are the exceptions to the above rule.

Comment: @murtaza52 the package manager has nothing to do with the kernel. The package manager is an application that is installed on the filesystem and manages installing software on the filesystem. If it's visible on the path and the fileystem is laid out correctly, it will work. In a container, this is the case.

Comment: To further clarify: the filesystem of the container is completely separated from the filesystem of the host. Think of a `chroot` (if you already used that), or a dual boot (even if it's a bit of a stretch :-))